# Getting the .html() of an element using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this code in jQuery:

```
$("a.crt_albmed").click(function(){
    page = $(this).attr('alt');
    loader = "<img src='/images/al_loading.gif' width='20' height='20' />";
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/for_photos/"+page,
        beforeSend: function(){
            $(this).append(loader);
        },
        success: function(grabbed){
            //$("#load_div").html(grabbed);
        }
    });
});
```

Which loads up a page in a giving `div`. Now my problem is this. I want to append the string `loader` in the `.html()` of the link before it loads up but the problem is it doesn't work. Now I tried changing the html content like this `$(this).html("good");` but it still doesn't change. I thought this `$("#myDiv").html("good");` is the same with `$(this).html("good");` but I don't know why it's not working. I am still new to jQuery. Please anyone with an idea how to make this work?

Comment: when used within a function `this`'s scope is associated with that `function` and not the outer `function`.

Comment: looking at it, you might want to go with `$("#myDiv").html("good");` and `NOT` use `this` anyway. The below answers that use `this` are going to REPLACE `a.crt_albmed` and NOT `#myDiv`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to set up the context for `this` - try replacing

`beforeSend: function(){
            $(this).append(loader);
        },`

with

`// define element before ajax call
    var $el = $(this);
    // ...
    // ajax call, then:
    beforeSend: function(){
            $el.append(loader);
        },
//...`

Try that and see how it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

"good" is not valid HTML, either use valid html, or use the .text() function, i.e.

Use:

```
$("#myDiv").text("good");
```

or

```
$("#myDiv").html("<span>good</span>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `this` at a place where `this` is no longer the button you would hope it would be. Good practice is to either save the button in a variable(`var self = this`) or just assign the html by selecting the button again(`$("a.crt_albmed").append(loader);`).

Try this:

```
$("a.crt_albmed").click(function(){

    var self = this // This will store the button

    page = $(this).attr('alt');
    loader = "<img src='/images/al_loading.gif' width='20' height='20' />";
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/for_photos/"+page,
        beforeSend: function(){
                $(self).append(loader);
        },
        success: function(grabbed){
                //$("#load_div").html(grabbed);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
beforeSend: function(){
   $(this).append(loader);
}
```

'this' inside the beforesend function points to the object passed to the $.ajax, if you want to access the current clicked object inside the beforesend function do something like this.

```
$("a.crt_albmed").click(function(){
    var clickedEle = this;
    page = $(this).attr('alt');
    loader = "<img src='/images/al_loading.gif' width='20' height='20' />";
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/for_photos/"+page,
        beforeSend: function(){
            $(clickedEle).append(loader);
        },
        success: function(grabbed){
            //$("#load_div").html(grabbed);
        }
    });
});
```

save the reference and use that in beforesend, because the object that calls the beforesend is the object passed to the $.ajax not the clicked element